# Retrieve Options from function other than graphics objects

Tags: function-construction

We can retrieve information about used Options for Graphics via:

```
Options[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}], "AspectRatio"]
(* {AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio} *)
```

even if we change Options, as in:

```
Options[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}, AspectRatio -> 1], "AspectRatio"]
(* {AspectRatio -> 1 *)
```

Is there a simple trick to archive the same behavior for arbitrary (such as self defined) functions that are no graphics objects? This behavior would be useful for retrieving e.g. used parameters of a modeled system for annotating Plots, Legends etc.

Edit:

```
Options[f] = {"Amplitude" -> 1, "Frequency" -> 1};
f[x_, OptionsPattern[]] := 
OptionValue["Amplitude"]*Cos[2 \[Pi] *OptionValue["Frequency"]*x]

Options[f]
Options[f[0, "Amplitude" -> 2] ]
(* {"Amplitude" -> 1, "Frequency" -> 1} *)
(* {} *)
```

Comment: I expected `HoldAll` to do the trick, but it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

In `Options[f[0, "Amplitude" -> 2]]`,  the `Options` function never sees `f[0, "Amplitude" -> 2]` because it immediately evaluates to `2`:

```
In[10]:= f[0, "Amplitude" -> 2]
Out[10]= 2
```

It's the same as writing `Options[2]`, which of course returns `{}`.

You need to prevent this evaluation either by not defining `f` or by using

```
In[11]:= Options[Unevaluated@f[0, "Amplitude" -> 2]]
Out[11]= {"Amplitude" -> 2}
```

Comment: The output for `Options[Unevaluated@f[0, "Amplitude" -> 2]]` I'd like to get is `{"Amplitude" -> 2, Frequency ->1}`

Comment: @Sascha I believe you have to get that manually starting with `Options[f]` and `Options[f[...]]`.  Also, you'd need to explicitly ask for the option you want.  `Options[Graphics[]]` is also `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Options[f] = {opt1 -> 2};
SetOptions[f, opt1 -> 1];
Options[f]

(* {opt1 -> 1} *)
```

Comment: I should have clarified that I want to use `OptionsPattern`, see the edit in my question